# install date time picker on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, date, time

I've recently created a kiosk which uses `openbox` and `xorg` in order to be able to show the browser. Is there also a way that I can run some command in the server and it will open a graphical date and time window? something like windows date and time window?

My desired end-result is to run this command through an AJAX request from my application which rans on chrome and then it will launch the date and time picker so the user can change the date and time.

Comment: @Anthon The application runs in the browser, however, the time the application shows is derived from the server time. I ensured that when played a little bit with the GMT timezone. I want to somehow show a graphical date and time picker that will change the server date and time

Comment: @Anthon The server isn't connected to the internet. I don't care which time and date the users set as it doesn't really matter. However, I do need to offer that feature

Comment: @Anthon Perhaps I haven't explained myself properly. The server is set on a small PC. I provide the costumer with the PC and it automatically runs the application on startup. The user never touches the server directly nor he has access to network. I just need to have a nice interface so he can, if he wishes, to change the date and time. The kiosk is built upon ubuntu server so there is no Desktop installed.

Comment: The server is set on a small PC, what does that mean. You have a small PC and physically on top of that you have some other piece of hardware that you call the server? Probably your and my terminology don't match but I don't understand how the client machine is connected to the server machine and how these communicate and what you want to run on which machine.

Comment: @Anthon The "small PC" is the server itself. I'm handing the application to my customer with that "small PC". When the customer purchases the application, he gets a "small PC" which he just need to plug to a monitor and everything works from there. The "small PC" is pre-configured by me. What I meant by server is that on that "small PC" I've installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 along with `xorg`, `openbox` and `google-chrome`. The "small PC" is set to once it's has booted, it launched xorg, openbox and google-chrome in a kiosk mode with the application loaded.

Comment: If this is a stand-alone machine, and not a server then, just have the apache (or whatever serves the application that chrome connects to) start the date/time-picker of your choice. Make sure that the desktop can be connected to (`xhost +`) and that you change the owner and permissions on the date-time picker (`chmod +s ..` and `chown root ..` or similar) so that it is allowed to actualy change the time. I would myself still go for a browser based date-timepicker and have the backend httpserver call a commandline command (e.g. date with SUID bit set) that actually changes the time.

Comment: @Anthon I plan to implement the browser approach only if I can't get a graphical date and time picker. Can you please show me how I would get the graphical date and time picker as you suggested with the `xhost`? (I'm not really sure what is it tbh)

Comment: xhost sets the permissions who can connect to your display. By default some other user (like the one running the http-server will not be allowed to connect and hence cannot display).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should IMO not launch the systems date-time picker unless your customers insist on their look and feel.

If you really need to do so you need the http-server (apache, ngnix or whaterver else you are using) to start a program that displays on X surface. For this you need to:

- trigger something in your backend software that will start the program Y that is the datetimepicker. You can do this base on access to a specific URL, but you will need to change the backend software running on your server.
- give the appropriate rights to program Y to connect to X ( `xhost +` and start the program with appropriate display e.g. by setting the DISPLAY environment variables.
- give the appropriate rights to the program Y to change the date on the machine (this might involve giving it root permissions via SUID rights

A much more clean solution would IMO be to prompt for the date-time in some input field (or use some fancy JavaScript based picker) and sent the selected time to the http-server which then still needs to call a program with enough rights to actually set the date and time on the server, but it would be a much more simple program, or even be `/bin/date` with the SUID bit set. That way you don't need to connect to the host display and can more easily check if the date-time input by the user makes sense.

---

AJAX on its own will not help you, as it needs to talk to some backend (http-server). It makes little difference for the backend to get an AJAX initiated call or some normal URL access through some link of form based button.

Comment: Thanks. What's SUID? I'm using Nginx, how would I wire up what you said here? (I'm not a linux pro user, just tinkered with it a bit) I would love to see some code which can at-least point me to the right way

Comment: SUID is the bit indicating that a program can run as the owner of that program (try `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` it should have `-rwsr-xr-x` the `s` in there is the suid bit that is set. What application are you running on nginx? Something like django? If you are just serving files, that will not be enough to start some program.

Comment: I'm using PHP with PHP-FPM. How would you set that SUID?

Comment: You set that bit logging in as root, you only do it once. E..g. if you do `chmod +s /bin/date` will give you a date command that can be run as a normal user (and still change the time). Whether PHP can call some other program to run I don't know.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: PHP can run bash commands. It will do so as `www-data` user and group. In Windows, what I've done is run the command `%systemroot%\system32\control.exe timedate.cpl,Date and Time` with php's `exec()` function. It resulted in opening the date-time picker instance. Can I somehow do the same in order to achieve that end-result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24754/discussion-between-anthon-and-kfirba).